# Strange bevavior of f:setPropertyActionListener inside ui:repeat and accordion

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

In a jsf/primefaces(version 6.2) project I have this peace of code to display a list of records in an accordion.
All the records are displayed correctly.
 
Inside a `ui:repeat` I have a `p:commandButton` to be able to save some text fragments (fragmt) using `f:setPropertyActionListener`.
 
 
I'm also implementing a second `f:setPropertyActionListener` to get an object (`sRes`). This one is working fine.
 
But the `currentFrag` variable get always populated with the text framgments from the last accordion.

```
<h:form id="accord" >
<p:accordionPanel value="#{myBean.lucSearchResults}" var="sRes" multiple="true">
<p:tab title="#{sRes.score}"> 

    <ui:repeat value="#{sRes.frags}" var="fragmt">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="10">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
        <h:outputText value="#{fragmt}" escape="false"/>
        <hr/>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="10">
        <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.saveFrag}" value="Save" >
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{sRes}" target="#{myBean.currentSearchResult}" />
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{fragmt}" target="#{myBean.currentFrag}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </ui:repeat>
</p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

I have a long experience with JSF and Java. I have no explanation for this strange behavior. 
Any help or pointer on this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this using Primefaces 7.0, Mojarra 2.3.3, JVM 1.8.0_152-b16, Apache Tomcat 9.0.21, Openwebbeans 2.0.7 using this example:

```
<h:form id="frm">
    <p:accordionPanel id="accordion" value="#{myBean.cats}" var="cat"
        multiple="true">
        <p:tab id="tab" title="#{cat.name}">
            <ui:repeat var="kid" value="#{cat.kitten}">
                <h:panelGroup id="group">
                    <p:commandButton id="cmdSubmit" action="#{myBean.doSomething()}"
                        value="submit #{cat.name} - #{kid.name} " process="@form"
                        update=":frm:output">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{cat}"
                            target="#{myBean.cat}" />
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{kid}"
                            target="#{myBean.kid}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </ui:repeat>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>

    <h:outputText id="output"
        value="#{myBean.cat.name} - #{myBean.kid.name}" />
</h:form>
```

This is my bean:

```
package my.package;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 43L;

    private List<Cat> cats;

    private Cat cat;

    private Cat kid;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        cats = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final Cat cat = new Cat();
            cats.add(cat);
            cat.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            cat.setKitten(new ArrayList<>());
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                final Cat kid = new Cat();
                kid.setName(i + "." + j);
                cat.getKitten().add(kid);
            }
        }
    }


    public void doSomething() {
        System.err.println(cat.getName() + " / " + kid.getName());
    }

    // getters & setters ...

    public static class Cat {
        private String name;
        private List<Cat> kitten;

        // getters & setters ...
    }
}
```

When hitting e.g. the command button reading "5 - 5.4" the output is "5 - 9.4":

[image: UI screenshot]

---

When replacing p:accordion/p:tab with ui:repeat, this example works as expected. This suggests it has something todo with primefaces dynamic tabs <strike>and might be worth a bug report</strike>.

When replacing `process="@form"` with `process="@this"` or `process="group"` it also works as expected and outputs the correct label of the button pressed.

---

**An even better work around** for this is to use the [`p:repeat`](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/repeat.xhtml) component implemented to solve [known incompatibilities](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/999) between tabView/accordion/dataTable and different `ui:repeat` implementations.

Comment: Does it fail with a tabview too?

Comment: Yes it does @Kukeltje

Comment: I can confirm, placing `process="@this"` in the commandButton it works as expected. Thank you very much @Selaron. Nice work!

Comment: @codyLine I added a hint to better use `p:repeat` instead of `ui:repeat` here. Didn't even know this component exists up to now.

Comment: Cool. I'm using `p:repeat` too now.